# angular-ui-router doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I don't manage to route using ui-router. It does work for me with ng-route, so I must have missed something basic. There is no error but I don't get any view.

The following code does **not** work (except for the otherwise statement):

```
angular.module("employeesApp", ["ui.router"])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('employeeList', {
            url: "/employees",
            templateUrl: "components/employee_list/employeeListView.html",   
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/employees");
});
```

The following code does work:

```
angular.module("employeesApp", ["ngRoute"])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    var employeeListRoute = {
        templateUrl: "components/employee_list/employeeListView.html"
    };

    var otherwiseRoute = employeeListRoute;

    $routeProvider
        .when("/employeeList", employeeListRoute)
        .otherwise(otherwiseRoute);
```

Here is my index.html (omitted not relevant elements):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="employeesApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.route.js"></script>
    <script src="components/employee_list/employeeListCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ng-view />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to use ui-router?

Comment: Any error in console? have you included `angular-ui-router.js`?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar there are no errors in the console, and I have included angular-ui-router.js. As a proof: the otherwise statement does work.

Comment: There is a good chance you are missing the ui-view directive: `<body><div ui-view></div></body>`. Do you have `ui-view` anywhere to load the views ?

Comment: @Amin Meyghani I don't miss it, I have it. I have mentioned that the code that uses ng-route does work.

Comment: can you paste in the code where you load the view ?

Comment: @Amin Meyghani I've pasted my index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AminMeyghani already said, you should be using `ui-view` instead of `ng-view` directive to get router know that relative view should be loaded inside `ui-view` directive

```
<div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tSe7qx2HYdFIVs8fVoRY?p=preview)